# Avoiding circular dependency with modal utility class?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a `utilities` class that handles common things throughout my app such as showing alerts, loading spinners, and modals. Right now on my home page I'm attempting to call `utilities.openModal()` but am getting a circular dependency with the following warning message:

> [ng] WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
>
> [ng] src/app/pages/users/add-entry/add-entry.page.ts -> src/app/services/utilities/utilities.service.ts -> src/app/pages/users/add-entry/add-entry.page.ts
>
> [ng] WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
>
> [ng] src/app/services/utilities/utilities.service.ts -> src/app/pages/users/add-entry/add-entry.page.ts -> src/app/services/utilities/utilities.service.ts

openModal function on utilities.service.ts:

```
openModal(page, enterAnimation = null, leaveAnimation = null) {
  // Create modal
  this.modalCtrl.create({
    component: page,
    enterAnimation: enterAnimation,
    leaveAnimation: leaveAnimation,
    componentProps: {
      utilities: UtilitiesService
    }
  }).then(m => m.present());
}

openEntryModal() {
  this.openModal(AddEntryPage);
}
```

I simply call that on my homepage component with `this.utilities.openEntryModal()` once the modal opens it throws the circular dependency warning. Any ideas why this is happening? I have a rough idea but can't pinpoint.

add-entry.page.ts imports:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { UtilitiesService } from 'src/app/services/utilities/utilities.service';
```

utilities.service.ts imports:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController, LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AnimationsService } from 'src/app/services/animations/animations.service';
import { AddEntryPage } from 'src/app/pages/users/add-entry/add-entry.page';
```

Comment: share the import sections of `src/app/pages/users/add-entry/add-entry.page.ts` and `src/app/services/utilities/utilities.service.ts`

Comment: @RezaRahmati Added.

Comment: @JoeScotto what was your final take on this? I also have the same use case, as workaround I give the requester the responsibility to send the `ComponentRef` which works but it feels wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It means in `utilities.service.ts` you imported `AddEntryPage` and in `add-entry.page.ts` you imported `UtilitiesService` and this will cause circular dependency

Based on your code seems you want to open modal of `AddEntryPage` component from `AddEntryPage` (which you imported the service)

If you imported the service for other functions it's better to break down the service, for example create another one called `modalService`

Comment: `AddEntryPage` is the component that opens in the modal, not what is opening the modal.

Comment: Do you want to open same component as modal from it self?

Comment: I might be getting a bit confused but the basic flow is that on my home page there is a button and that will open the add-entry modal. I don't want to open add-entry from add-entry, I'm wanting to have a header button that will open add-entry from anywhere within the app hence why I'm trying to get it on a single utilties class so I can just import that and then reference it.

Comment: @JoeScotto then what is the reason to import `UtilitiesService`in `AddEntryPage `?

Comment: I use that to dismiss my modals. `utilities.dismissModal()` as well as other things that are used throughout my app such as loading spinners, alerts, etc. This way I don't have to create and import them on each file since the overall implementation is always the same just the text is different based on which component is using it.